# useFactory vs useValue with AoT compilation

Tags: angular, angular-di

I use `window.location` to setup for injectable.
In my module near imports I define variable

```
const flag = window.location.search.includes('flag');
...
{ provide: FLAG, useValue: flag },
```

and it works as expected with JIT compilation
But when I switch to AoT it breaks
`useFactory` works in both cases

```
export function flagFactory() {
  return window.location.search.includes('flag');;
}
...
{ provide: FLAG, useFactory: flagFactory },
```

Why do I get `undefined` with `useValue` and `true` with `useFactory`?

Comment: where do you define this part of your code `const flag = ...`?

Comment: in RootModule together with imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `AoT` statically analyses your code outside of the `NgModule` structure. So it sees `window.location.search.includes` and executes this ahead of time. But at compilation time, this will obviously return `undefined`. In the case of using a `factory`, it will not try to execute the body ahead of time, only at run-time.

It's one of the (many) pitfalls of AOT. Always try to have every symbol statically analyzable